# In Laravel getting error after http://localhost:8000/auth/register url

Tags: php, laravel

*ReflectionException* in

> C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   line 776: Class App\Provider\AppServiceProvider does not exist

Comment: lol, The Error says the Class doesn't Exist, That's what i would also say :)

Comment: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar] is not instantiable.  when i  put url http://localhost:8000/auth/register  give error

Comment: Have you updated the compiled.php ?

Comment: Just do `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: No Actually  i am doing php artisan queue:flush then get this error

Comment: queue:flush will just delete all the failed jobs.. What is the exact error now ? Class not found ?

Comment: Unfortunately in app folder  auth folder was deleted from me  i am download laravel setup  from  internet copy from auth folder paste  in my project . i am using laravel 5 vesrion ..localhost:8000/auth/login  then  give error                                                          Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar] is not instantiable.

Comment: No No... You should not do it... If unfortunately deleted. Then you should have a fresh installation...

Answer (score 0):

when you found weird errors, just do a

```
composer update
```

it will help you rebuild your vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

Artisan is the command-line interface included with Laravel. 
Try this series of commands.

```
php artisan make:auth
php composer update
php composer dump-autoload
```